# NSPredicate with CoreData - property contains object that meets requirement

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, foundation

My `CoreData` object is called `Conversations`, and one of the properties is `messages` with type `[Message]`.

What I want to do is create a predicate that is equivalent to this:

```
conversationsFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate { object, dictionary in

    if let messages = dictionary?["messages"] as? [Message] {

        return messages.contains { !$0.triggeredNotification }

    } else { return false }

}
```

Unfortunately, the code above doesn't actually work with `CoreData`. I tried it and I get an error about an incompatible `NSPredicate`. I imagine the string `NSPredicate` looking something like this:

```
conversationsFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "messages CONTAINS message where triggeredNotification == false")
```

EDIT:

I believe the answer is something along these lines perhaps?

```
conversationsFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(messages, %x, %x.triggeredNotification == false)")
```

However, this causes a runtime crash.

Comment: How is the `messages` attribute defined in the data model editor?  If it is `transformable`, then (assuming you are fetching from a SQLite store), your search for a predicate is futile: the attribute will be stored as a blob of data and its content cannot be accessed via a predicate.

Comment: I ended up just fetching all of the objects stored, filtering out the ones I want to keep, then just using a for loop to manually deleteObject. I can afford to load them all into memory (properties included) because the highest number of objects that it should ever reach is around 20-30

Comment: If you have an array of all the conversations in memory, you could cast it as NSArray, then use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` with predicate "ANY messages.triggeredNotification == false".